# http4s client returns partial payload

Tags: scala, http4s

I'm using the `AsyncHttpClient` in http4s-0.19.0-M2 to make a client-call:

```
for {
    resp <- http.expectOr[String](GET(url)){ error =>
                error.as[String].map(body => throw new Exception(...)
            }
    _ <- doSomethingWithResponse(resp)
} yield ()
```

Occassiaonally the remote end times out, and I see the following in the log:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to remote.server.com after 60000 ms
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:50)
    at shade.cda.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:670)
    at shade.cda.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:745)
    at shade.cda.io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:473)
    at shade.cda.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However, it looks like `doSomethingWithResponse()` is still invoked, but with a partial `resp` string.  Is there a way to change this behavior so that the `http.expectOr` call fails if it can't retrieve the entire payload?